# Select an element without a particular child element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Example 1</th>
            <th>Example 2</th>
            <th>Example 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Example text 1</td>
            <td>Example text 2</td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to apply styles only to tds that don't include `input` tag.

How to do that?

Comment: You can't do that with CSS alone. CSS selectors cannot select an element depending on whether it has a specific child or not (atleast not yet).

Comment: Are there any other unique qualities of the `td` with `input` child? Such as, is it always the last `td` in the row?

Comment: No, it isn't always the last td in the row :(

Comment: Well, unless there's another quality that can be targeted, then it is solely a parent selector scenario, which unfortunately CSS cannot do (but Javascript can).