# Stylize parent element CSS

Tags: css

I would like to know how to style an element according to his son.

```css
.content p {
  text-indent: 20;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>
    <iframe></iframe>
  </p>
  
  <!--I have to modify this paragraph-->
  <p>4</p>
</div>
```

What do I need to do, is to modify the paragraph that has the iframe (`text-indent: 0`).

Comment: See this question that was asked a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34528737/3597276

Answer (score 0):

The best is to write something like

```
<p class="custom">...</p>
```

Then add style with

```
p.custom{
    /* Your styles here */
}
```